# Hide file extension is not working htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using mod_rewrite to hide **file** extension this code is working prefect but when i add slash at the end of url it's show error 500 internal server error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Please help me

Comment: Look at your server's error logs - it'll have more details, but undoubtedly you've introduced a syntax error into the rewrite stuff

Comment: this is not my code i also pick up from different blog but this is not working properly . as well as there is no error log else my Ip and user agent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when i add slash at the end of url it's show error 500 internal server error

This is because the slash is being grouped together in the `(.*)` and then referenced by `$1`, so a request like:

```
http://your.host.com/my_file/
```

is getting rewritten to:

```
http://your.host.com/my_file/.php
```

The reason is that the condition `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php` exists, because the trailing slash gets ignored. You just need to include the match against the trailing slash in your `RewriteRule`'s regex:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
```